# Advanced textbook for vector fields

Tags: textbooks, mathematical-analysis, vector-calculus

I am currently reading Spivak Calculus on Manifolds and Munkres Analysis on Manifolds.  I am looking for a more advanced text, especially on vector fields as they relate to the great conserved fields of physics.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Educators! A more appropriate place for your question could be [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/). You could delete your question here and post it over there. Good luck!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be seeking personal advice about a course of study.  As such, it is not really on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

This may not move in the directions of your greatest interests, but it is one option.
(Not my field so I cannot assess comparable books.)

> Eschrig, Helmut. *Topology and Geometry in Physics*. Vol. 822. Springer Science & Business Media, 2011.
>   [Springer link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540231257).
>   [Review by Jan Jerzy Sławianowski](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jgsp/1495677632).
>   Publisher summary: "Written as a set of largely self-contained extensive lectures, the book gives an introduction to topological concepts in gauge theories, BRST quantization, chiral anomalies, supersymmetric solitons and noncommutative geometry."

---

[image: Cover]

---

Note: Not to be confused with *Topology and Geometry for Physicists* by Charles Nash and Siddhartha Sen.